# Double click on Linkbutton on a repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I had link button on a repeater. My Question is how I'll be able to have linkbutton with a double click inside a repeater not a single click?

here's my code:

```
    <td class="style2">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' CommandName="Name" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Code") %>'>
    </asp:LinkButton></td>
```

C#

```
protected void rptrInsurance_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                switch (e.CommandName)
                {
                    case "Delete":
                        {
                            HCSInsurance oInsuranceDelete = new HCSInsurance();
                            Insurance oInsurance = new Insurance();

                            List<InsuranceLabel> lstName = oInsuranceDelete.RetrieveInsuranceList();
                            foreach (InsuranceLabel item in lstName)
                            {
                                var code = e.CommandArgument;
                                if (item.InsuranceCode.ID == code.ToString())
                                {
                                    oInsurance.InsuranceCode = item.InsuranceCode;
                                    oInsuranceDelete.DeleteInsurance(oInsurance);
                                    bind();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        break;
                    case "Edit":
                        {
                            Session["InsuranceCodeID"]= e.CommandArgument.ToString();  
                            Response.Redirect("~/InsuranceCarrierNew.aspx");
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        {
                           //bind();
                            HCSInsurance oHCSInsurance = new HCSInsurance();
                            Insurance oInsurance = new Insurance();
                            string code = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
                            oInsurance = oHCSInsurance.RetrieveInsurance(code);
                            Labelvisible();
                            //string

                            lblName.Text = oInsurance.Name;
                            lblAddress.Text = oInsurance.Address1;
                            lblCity.Text = oInsurance.City;
                            lblState.Text = oInsurance.State;
                            lblZip.Text = oInsurance.Zip;
                            lblDphone.Text = oInsurance.ContactTelephone;
                            lblDfax.Text = oInsurance.ContactFax;

                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware the goal you want to achieve exist in the client side, there is a [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) for double-click event, like:

```
$('id').dblclick(function() {
     // Call something here.
});
```

The downside of this, you might want to change your implementation in having an AJAX call instead of doing a postback, it might be possible also to just submit the form and edit the necessary arguments for your back-end code.